# Page auth with php am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, if-statement, location

I'm creating a website with SESSION and I'm trying to make the index be viewed only by users, but even I'm login or logout my script still redirecting.

I created:

```
<?php 
if($_SESSION['id'] == true){
  break;
} else {
  header('Location:nologin.php');
}
```

?>

But when I do login, script still redirecting to nologin.php and I changed to:

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['id'] == false){
header('Location:nologin.php');
}
?>
```

And the problem still occurs, How do I do?

Answer (score 0):

You've stumbled on a wrong technique how to check if a session is set.

**Quick solution**

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
   header('Location:nologin.php');
}
```

#### What went wrong?

Let's assume the `$_SESSION["id"]` is a string and **not** a boolean.

```
if($_SESSION["id"] == true){
    echo "will always return true <br>";
}
if($_SESSION["id"] == false){
    echo "will always return false<br>";
}
```

You can see this especially when you use the `===` (indentical) opperater, as it will never be identical.

```
if($_SESSION["id"] === true){
    echo "will never return true <br>";
}
```

If you would be checking if a session is a `boolean` the scenario changes. 
I would suggest reading the documentation on [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)